# How to connect X-Lite softphone from host to guest vm with asterisk?

Tags: networking, asterisk, voip, opensips

I am desperate. I've install asterisk on vm 1 (centos) and opensips on vm2(centos), and everything works well so far. Now I need to connect softphone from host to vm1 (to make a call (I'm traying to set up auto-dial out system))) and don't know how to. I use host-only networking between vm's

vm1 - 192.168.56.3
vm2 - 192.168.56.4
host - I've set up rule in firewall, to make traffic enabled between vm's and host, but can't ping from guest to host/ host to guest.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way - use bridged network to your router.

But host-only also work ok(at least in vmware and virtualbox), check your firewall rules

Comment: I've set inbound rules in my Windows firewall for 2 vm', but can't ping host.